# How do I preserve fonts and images when sending AI files?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, images

[image]I work with a team member on a few graphic design projects. After she creates the template she likes, she sends it to me to edit the text and and adjust the layout.

The problem I am having is with the fonts and images she is using. For some reason my program will not recognize her fonts or even the images she uses. We both have Adobe Illustrator CC, but she has a Dell and I use a Mac. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You just use the Package feature found under File->Package or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

Make sure all the boxes are checked and pick the appropriate file paths to save.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. However, it did not work. I am still receiving the message that AI cannot find the images or fonts. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your post with a screenshot of the error?

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, usually you would click replace and navigate to the folder where the files are. Are there no images in that folder?

Comment: I have the images on my computer so I have navigated to them and that part worked. However, the fonts are not staying the same. How do I keep the fonts were I can still edit the text?

Comment: The fonts are* saying the same message.

Comment: You will have to install each of the missing fonts. Navigate to the fonts and double-click them. Font book should open up and you should see an install button.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding it seems the images are not embedded into the artwork, that is why it’s requesting a link to the original image. The one sending the files has to embed them (to embed, just place the image on artwork as required then you will see the embed but appear then click on it).

As for the fonts, if you have to edit then have them installed on your machine then when you open the artwork it will pick them up automatically. If you are not editing the text then probably the one who is sending needs to convert them into curves before sending you the artwork.

Comment: To add to this; Adobe is generally quite decent with switching between windows/mac, so I doubt that is the problem.